# Woocommerce hook after product is published

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I'm using below

```
add_action('transition_post_status', 'my_product_update', 1000, 3);

function my_product_update($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
    if($new_status == 'publish' && $post->post_type == "product") {
         $product_id = $post->ID;
         $product = new WC_Product($product_id);
         echo $product->get_price();
    }
}
```

I figure it out that `$product->get_price()` is `string(0) ""`.
I think it beacause I retrieve the price before it's saved.
But I can retrieve the name by using `$product->post->post_title`

Any idea how I can get the price right after the product is published?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

```
function wpa104760_default_price( $post_id, $post ){  
    echo $price = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', true);
    echo $sale = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price', true);
   // exit;

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'wpa104760_default_price',1000,2 );
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but it doesn't work. The result still remains the same.

Comment: @Tungshev I have update my answer. this should work. thanks.

Comment: It works perfectly. You're genius. I feel really grateful.